# exim: user with several email addresses (as with "virtual" file in postfix)

Tags: exim

In postfix, there is the "virtual" file which contains a simple list of email-addresses and the users they belong to:

```
myname@mydomain.com                       user
my.name@mydomain.com                      user
my_name@mydomain.com                      user
myname@myotherdomain.com                  user2
someone@myotherdomain.com                 user2
```

This basically allows "user" to have more email addresses than just "user@mydomain.com" and it allows to point "myname@mydomain.com" to a different user than "myname@myotherdomain.com".

How can one replicate this behavior in Exim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not easy, but I found the solution myself:

Just add this to the exim configuration:

```
domains_virtual:
  driver = redirect
  data = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/path_to_my_email_aliases}}
```

The important part is the "@$domain" part, so that you can specify users and domains and not just the users (as with the /etc/aliases directive)

Answer (score 0):

There is standard file `/etc/aliases` that contains the same pairs alias-destination. Don't forget to execute `newaliases` after editing.

UPD: you have to provide pairs in form:

```
alias@domain.tld:   user
alias2:             user1 user2
```

Second form allows to send copies of message to the number of recipients.

Comment: The first line of your example does not work.